# Problems trying to install/uninstall Docker

Tags: windows, docker, docker-desktop

After trying to install Docker on Windows, I got a note that my WSL version wasn't correct. After updating it, Docker still refused to launch, without giving any clear error messeges, so I decided to re-install it. To do so, I, quite foolishly in hignsight, just deleted the folder in Program Files, without using any proper uninstall tools. After that, I tried to use the installer, however it still tells me that I have an existing up-to-date installation. I tried to uninstall it through Windows Settings, but it can't find the "Docker Desktop Installer.exe" - it was in the folder I deleted. Any suggestions of what I can do in this situations? Thanks.

Comment: Is the folder just gone? Did you check the recycle bin?

Comment: Sadly, I cleared the recycle bin, thinking the installer was somehow seeing the folder in there. I really shouldn't have.

Comment: Then I don't think you'll be able to do much; other than trying some 3rd party tools to remove its data from Registry and other places -- or resetting the PC.

Comment: Clearing the Registry helped, thanks!